# Fasttext how to load a .csv column into model.predict

Tags: python, fasttext

I am new to python and NLP.

I have followed this tutorial (https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html) to train my fasttxt supervised model in Python.

I have a csv with Text column and I would like to predict labels to ever row from the file.
My question is how can I load (transform) the csv column in the predict input and save the label.

```
model.predict("Which baking dish is best to bake a banana bread ?", k=-1, threshold=0.5)
```

instead of this ( the text in ""Which baking....") I would like to load row by row and save the label preferably in the new column in same csv.

I would appropriate any help or maybe a tutorial I could follow.

So far I have tried to convert the column in to to list with pandas and numpy array but both came back with "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find'"

Comment: Please post some example rows of your CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this CSV as example:

`index;id;text;author
0;id26305;This process, however, afforded me no means of...;EAP
1;id17569;It never once occurred to me that the fumbling...;HPL
2;id11008;In his left hand was a gold snuff box, from wh...;EAP
3;id27763;How lovely is spring As we looked from Windsor...;MWS
4;id12958;Finding nothing else, not even gold, the Super...;HPL
5;id22965;A youth passed in solitude, my best years spen...;MWS
6;id09674;The astronomer, perhaps, at this point, took r...;EAP
7;id13515;The surcingle hung in ribands from my body.      ;EAP
8;id19322;I knew that you could not say to yourself 'ste...;EAP
9;id00912;I confess that neither the structure of langua...;MWS`

You can use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import fastText as ft

# here you load the csv into pandas dataframe
df=pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv',sep=';')

# here you load your fasttext module
model=ft.load_model(MODELPATH)

# line by line, you make the predictions and store them in a list
predictions=[]
for line in df['text']:
    pred_label=model.predict(line, k=-1, threshold=0.5)[0][0]
    predictions.append(pred_label)

# you add the list to the dataframe, then save the datframe to new csv
df['prediction']=predictions
df.to_csv('csv_file_w_pred.csv',sep=';',index=False)
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank you so much !

Comment: Hi Anakin , just on more question if you don't mind. How would you change this loop to to save more than one label per row ? Lest say right it now it saves a first label from the model and if the output would be like this      (('__label__1',
  '__label__2',
  '__label__3',
  '__label__4',
  '__label__5'),
 array([0.2950488 , 0.25392196, 0.10041688, 0.05670581, 0.05045504])) , how would you save this ?

Comment: You only have to use:
pred_label=model.predict(line, k=-1, threshold=0.5)

without indexes