# fasttext error: predict processes one line at a time (remove '\n')

Tags: pandas, fasttext

Hi I have a dataframe column contains text. I want to use fasttext model to make prediction from it.
I can achieve this by passing an [array of text](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html) to fasttext model.

```
import fasttext
d = {'id':[1, 2, 3], 'name':['a', 'b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I removed '\n' from the series

```
name_list = df['name'].tolist()
name_list = [name.strip() for name in name_list]
```

and make prediction `model.predict(name_list)`

However, I got `ValueError: predict processes one line at a time (remove '\n')`

I don't have '\n' in the list and `'\n' in name_list` returns `False`

I also found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081066/fasttext-how-to-load-a-csv-column-into-model-predict) with the similar issue but still got the same error.

```
predictions=[]
for line in df['name']:
    pred_label=model.predict(line, k=-1, threshold=0.5)[0][0]
    predictions.append(pred_label)
df['prediction']=predictions
```

Answer (score 7):

Before giving model.predict(name_list), try giving a for loop:

```
for item in name_list:
   item = item.replace("\n"," ")
   model.predict(item)
```